# Change directory via cmd.exe doesn't work

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd, command-line-interface, command-prompt

I am trying to change directory via

```
cd d:
```

Doesn't work. I tried other variations of same process but doesn't work.
As if command prompt doesn't recognize D drive.

[image: cmd cd screenshot]

Comment: You are only changing the active directory on drive d (or you would if you did specify `cd D:\stuff` for example). But you are not switching to that drive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change directory in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753986/how-to-change-directory-in-windows)

Comment: I would be curious to know the mentioned variations ;-)

Comment: You can use `cd /d d:\ ` - the `/d` changes the drive.

Comment: I tried cd D:\ , cd D: , CD D:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command prompt won't change directory to another drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065421/command-prompt-wont-change-directory-to-another-drive)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just type `D:`. You don't need to input the `cd` to change drives.

Answer (score 1):

#### The short answer

The correct way to go from a random place on your `C:` drive to the root of your `D:` drive, is the following command :

```
cd /d d:\
```

---

#### More details

If you're somewhere random on your `D:\` drive, and you want to go to the root of your drive, you can use this command :

```
cd d:\
```

If you're somewhere random on your `D:\` drive, and you want to go to a specific folder on your drive, you can use this command :

```
cd d:\path\to\my\folder
```

If you're on a different drive, and you want to go to the root of your `D:\` drive, you can use this command :

```
cd /d d:\
```

If you're on a different drive, and you want to go to a specific folder on your `D:` drive, you can use this command :

```
cd /d d:\path\to\my\folder
```

If you're on a different drive, and you want to go to the last open folder of you `D:` drive, you can use this command :

```
cd /d d:
```

As a shorthand for `cd /d d:`, you can also use this command :

```
d:
```

Comment: An addition: The command ``cd \`` can be used to change to root of current drive independent on drive letter. And the command `cd \path\to\my\folder` can be used to change current directory to a specific directory on current drive independent on drive letter relative to root directory. A path starting with ``\`` is relative to root of current drive. A path starting with ``..\`` references parent directory of current directory. And a path starting with and ``.\`` or none of those 3 strings is relative to current directory.