# I am trying to change directory in CMD but it is not working. it will return to current directory, see this:

Tags: cmd

```
C:\Users\vk Yadav>cd d:
D:\ 
C:\Users\vk Yadav>
```

Why it's happening?

Comment: @Stephan, is it possible you rather change your colure link to point directly to your answer in that link? I do not completely agree to the `D:` standalone command as demonstrated in my answer and yours in the link.

Comment: @Gerhard: I did (https://stackoverflow.com/a/17754694/2152082). It seems, SO has changed the Duplicate-Feature to only be able to point to questions, not answers anymore (like I'm used to). What a pity - I too disagree with the accepted answer there (it works, but it isn't the most elegant solution).

Comment: Ok thank you @Stephan, I suppose The link you have in the comment is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Reading `cd /?` help shows you that when changing directories to different drives requires `/d` option.

```
cd /d D:\
```

but using

```
cd /d D:
```

will only change to the drive with previous path, similar as standalone `D:` command

The command obviously works with appended folders.

```
cd /d "D:\Some Folder\"
```

If you only want to changes drives, then just doing

```
D:
```

Will change to the drive. But if you were in a specific directory on `D:` prior to swopping to `C:\` then running `D:` will land you back in that dir. The following demonstrates this, you can test it yourself by copying it, add an actual directory name where I have `Some Folder` and paste into your `cmd` window.

```
echo off & cls
cd "%userprofile%"
cd
cd /d "D:\Some Folder\"
cd
D:
cd
C:
cd
cd /d D:
cd
cd /d C:
cd
cd /d D:\
cd
cd /d C:\
cd
```

Running the above on my system (note I use `Z:\` instead of `D:\`)
[image]

So if you intend to only land exactly on the drive or drive\dir, then just use `cd /d path`

Answer (score 0):

type D: and press enter. so you can move to D drive

Answer (score 0):

`cd` means *change directory*. You don't use it to change drives. Typing `cd D:` tells you what the current directory is on drive `D:`.

To change drives, just type the new drive letter followed by :, as in `D:` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To learn what `cd` does, type `cd /?` at a command prompt.

Comment: Yes.. however, if you were previously in `D:\Program Files\Acrobat"` doing just `D:` will land you back in `D:\Program Files\Acrobat"` which would require a new command `cd \` to land exactly in the intended path.

Comment: Apologies, That last part in my comment was meant to be cd \