# How could I resolve missing or invalid .exe on debugger of VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to debug my little program, but it's like it doesn't exist main.exe, but it exists.

[image]

My code is this simple:

[image]

And my launch.json is this one:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    
    {
        "name": "cpp.exe - Compilar y depurar el archivo activo",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": true,
        "cwd": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Habilitar la impresión con sangría para gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: cpp.exe build active file"
    }
]
```

}

I don't know what it's wrong. Thank you.

My build output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwnXf.png)

And my task.json is this one:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVI5V.png)

Comment: Not in executable format suggests the build is incorrect. You're producing something and calling it an exe, but it's not an exe, or at least isn't an exe when the debugger looks at it. Please add the build instruction that VS Code generates and the json file responsible for building.

Comment: I would never use a path that contains spaces or `+`. Not saying that is the issue here, but it's one more possible problem, and completely unnecessary.

Comment: Your first test would be to open a cmd.exe window and change directory to the location of the executable and see if you can run it from there.

Comment: @john I've changed my path to PruebaCPlusPlus and still there is the same error.

Comment: @drescherjm  Sorry, I don't know how to change that directory ^^'. Could you explain it?

Comment: @user4581301 I've just changed the post, thank you. Anything you need to solve it.

Comment: the command in cmd.exe to change the current directory is `cd`. This should help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753986/how-to-change-directory-using-windows-command-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753986/how-to-change-directory-using-windows-command-line)

Comment: For build information there's got to be more than that. See what's in the Output tab.