". java" files which are saved in "d" and "e" drives, Didn't get compiled (Files were run from the VScode)
My hard drive has 3 partitions as c, d and e.
c drive is the main one.
I'm running these following codes through the VScode.Not the CMD or PowerShell also I didn't used the terminal section of the VScode.I just opened the files through the VScode and run them And I got the each following output
So here is what's happening
I'm Running the code saved in c
public class Test {
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("this is working");

    }

}

Output of the file which is saved in c
Running] cd "c:\lec c\" && javac Test.java && java Test
this is working

[Done] exited with code=0 in 3.176 seconds

I'm Running the code saved in d
public class Test {
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("this is working");

    }

}

Output of the file which is saved in d
[Running] cd "d:\lec d\" && javac Test.java && java Test
error: file not found: Test.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options

[Done] exited with code=2 in 0.593 seconds

I'm Running the code saved in e
public class Test {
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        System.out.println("this is working");

    }

}

Output of the file which is saved in e
[Running] cd "e:\lec e\" && javac Test.java && java Test
error: file not found: Test.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options

[Done] exited with code=2 in 0.532 seconds

I want to know why this is happening to the files saved in "d" and "e". The little that I know is the reason may involved with the environment variables But its not clear enough to me.
Can some one explain me the exact reason.
Thankyou for your time and effort.

Please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text instead. See also How To Ask and Stack Overflow Meta

It is caused by Windows Native Command not being able to change drives automatically. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753986/how-to-change-directory-using-windows-command-line

@Mirro Mutth  im using the VScode and the outputs are occuring at the "output" section.Instead of that , Do i have to use the "Terminal" section and locate to the file ?

The "output" section shows that VS Code attempted to execute cd X:\lec X . The VS Code should have opened a directory that is not in drive X, or in the user's working directory (By default it is located in C:\Users\<username>).

Show your directory structure, and your vscode workspace. Also you are using Code Runner, you should try to execute scripts using the official Java extension(Run Java).

You didn't say whether you were running from Powershell or Cmd.
If you are running from the cmd prompt, use cd /d.  If you just use cd it stays on whatever drive you were on.

I'm using the "VScode" ,and the outputs are happening at the "output" section of the VScode, Not in the terminal. So ,Do you mean that if we are running the files which are saved from outside the C drive, we need to locate to the exact file location Using the "terminal" ?   Because as i know the CMD or PowerShell is involved only if i use the "Terminal" am i correct?

What cup is saying is that if you're currently on C:, and you execute cd d:\whatever, you are still in C:. CD changes directories. Not drives. The /d option does let cd change drives. Just do what this answer says.

@rzwitserloot I didn't said he is wrong he is totally correct but the thing is I'm not using the commands. Because I'm not using the CMD or the PowerShell. In fact  there is not option to use them unless I use the terminal of the VScode. What I have done is   opened " .java"  files located in "D"  and "E"  drives using the VScode and just run them. Then it showed the errors at the "output" section of the VScode. its not happening when i run the exact file when that exact file stored in "C" drive. I'm seeking the particular reason for that. Thanks anyway.

@NVbasnayaka Hmm, sounds like a bug in VSC then. You might want to file a bug.

You must use Extension Pack for Java to run Java instead of Code Runner.
